# Can the scratch susceptibility of a given material be determined, given the breaking strength of another?

Tags: material-science

There was a [post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/124442/does-washing-rice-in-a-non-stick-pot-erode-the-non-stick-coating-over-time) in Seasoned Advice which piqued my personal interest (seeing as how I'm ABC myself).  Rice cooker pots are by no means "cheap", so I thought I'd look into it myself in order to see if I could arrive to a definitive answer.

My initial search led me to this paper:

[Porosity and hardness of long-grain Brown rice kernels in relation to their chemical compositions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0023643821003960) ([.pdf backup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AjSf1qOjl4WHvNI2amJUm4hxlfPTwKLj/view?usp=sharing))

...as well as these "specifications" (Note: Dupont has a disclaimer disqualifying their table as a "specification", basically due to data error tolerances/variability/lack of precision or control uniformity, but for lack of a better word...):

[Properties Of Teflon™ Coatings](https://intechservices.com/properties-of-teflon-coatings/) ([.pdf backup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ApjRK27yi51_f9GKxwg2eILRmYKQ3zqX/view?usp=sharing))

[Mechanical Properties of Teflon® Coatings](https://www.crestcoating.com/ccsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Mechanical-Properties-of-Teflon-Coatings.pdf) ([.pdf backup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AnjmHg2gf4P17BZsFL9mIk6ShNK-uSRX/view?usp=sharing))

Unfortunately, as far as I was able to determine, it seems that the properties enumerated by the study and the tables are not directly comparable (from a purely arithmetic perspective?), as the former derived "64.6 to 213.7 N" (which, if I'm understanding correctly, was given as Newtons — a unit of measure for **force** — for its measure of **tensile and breaking strength**, whereas of the latter sources, one had no quantitative measures *at all* and cited qualitative descriptors in-lieu of, and the other reported an ambiguous range — with no additional clarification of parameters save the "Scratch Resistance scratch master" — as "5.1kg–13.2kg", which is a mass measure.

As I understand it, when we talk about a material's "hardness" and "scratch susceptibility", the specific context needs to established in order to disambiguate the lexical term "hardness", which can apparently refer to a variety of distinct (but possibly) correlated material properties and characteristics.  For [example](https://qr.ae/pyFzVn), "Hardness correlates linearly to Ultimate Tensile Strength through the empirical (although theoretically [un]explained[sic]) equation `H=UTS/k`".

According to the [Encyclopedia of Materials: Science and Technology (2001)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials-science/scratch-hardness)...

> Scratch hardness is defined as the hardness of a material when it is scratched by a stylus dragged along its surface under a given load. Unlike pure indentation-based hardness tests, scratch hardness defines the resistance of material to plowing (i.e., a combination of indentation cum sliding) by a hard stylus...Many of the common tribological phenomena like sliding, abrasive, and cutting wear are characterized by a harder material plowing into the softer wearing material. Thus, for correlating the tribological performance of many materials, scratch hardness (Hs) is expected to be a better correlating parameter than the indentation hardness.

Unfortunately, I've gone about as far as my two-decade-old high school Physics B education is able to take me.  It seems there are cases where we can strongly correlate such properties based on empirical, but I lack the requisite knowledge to apply such relationships to the specified context in any meaningful manner.  Can someone kindly explain whether a definitive and quantitative or evidence-based answer can be derived from the given data?  Or if not, exactly how indeterminate is it (i.e., can we extrapolate a probabilistic answer with some degree of confidence?).  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If it were possible to predict things like scratch resistance from some list of first principles then there would be no need of the field of *materials science* nor its practitioners (like I once was).

It is such a complex business that the best you can do is to develop standard testing & characterization methodology so that meaningful data on things like scratch resistance can be collected. In the best case you could hope for, you could then derive useful general (semi-empirical) correlations between things like ultimate strength, yield strength, rockwell hardness, charpy impact, etc. and scratch resistance.

Comment: You wouldn't happened to have worked with rice grains and Teflon coatings at any point during your career, would you?  Haha.

Comment: Sorry, no! But I had a friend who worked in a rice mill's hull conveyor system and learned a lot about this from him.